# Coin Wallet Snap Package scam

Tags: snap

I have come across a scam app named Coin Wallet from the snap store. I am wondering what the process is for snap package reporting is, since I can't find information anywhere. What is the process for getting these apps taken down?

Comment: Yeah they're getting [hammered with scams](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/stop-the-line/39357?u=kyrofa) right now.

Comment: AreSnapsSafeYet.com ?

Answer (score 6):

Locate the page for that snap at https://snapcraft.io.

That snap's page will have a "report this app" link near the bottom.